# Do all proper functions have an affine minorant?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, affine-geometry

We learned that proper functions are the functions $\ f(x):\!E \to \bar R$ where $\ domf \neq \emptyset$ and $ \ f(x) > - \infty \ \ \ \forall \ \ x\in \!E$. Do these conditions guarantee that there exists an affine minorant of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what about: $\mathbb R$, $f(x)=-x^2$ ?

Comment: Just to be clear, the domain of the function is just the set of reals, and so it can never take the value $- \infty $ since x is never $- \infty$? (Also thanks for your answer!)